# Is an 'editing' tag really useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

[There are currently two questions with this tag](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editing) (or at least there are two questions on the 'newest' page), but the tag seems *way* too broad to be useful. I could understand *photo-editing* [and, in fact, I just edited one of the two questions and replaced the *editing* tag with *photo-editing*], but in a very real sense almost every software application covers 'editing'.

Comment: Note that this tag has already been removed from the questions and will be removed automatically once the maintenance script kicks in.

Answer (score 7):

I think an *editing* tag is overbroad.

Comment: I agree - if it's for photo-editing, make a photo-editing tag, etc...

Comment: Makes sense, there is also a video-editing tag.